Proving that $T(n)=16T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+n! \in \Theta(n!)$
I am trying to prove that $T(n)\in\Theta(n!)$ for the following recurrence using the master theorem:
$\qquad T(n) = 16T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+  n!$
My attempt
We have that $f(n) = n! \in \Omega(n^{\log_416+\varepsilon})$ which means that we are in case 3 so we have to check the regularity condition:
$
\qquad 16f\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) \le c f(n)\quad\text{ for some $c < 1$}\\
\qquad 16\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)! \le c n!\quad (*)
$
Since we are interested in what happens for large values of $n$, we can get rid of the factorials using Stirling's approximation:
$\qquad n! \overset{n\to\infty}\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$
So the inequality $(*)$ becomes:
$
\qquad 16 \sqrt{2\pi \left(\frac{n}{4}\right)}(\frac{n/4}{e})^{n/4} \le c \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n\\
\qquad 16 \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}(\frac{n}{4e})^{n/4} \le c \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n\\
\qquad c \ge 16 \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}(\frac{n}{4e})^{n/4}(\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n)^{-1}\\
\qquad c \ge 16 \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{n}{4e})^{n/4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(\frac{e}{n})^n\\
\qquad c \ge 8 \frac{n^{n/4}}{4^{n/4}e^{n/4}} \frac{e^n}{n^n}\\
\qquad c \ge 8 \frac{n^{n/4-n}}{4^{n/4}e^{n/4-n}}\\
\qquad c \ge \frac{8}{4^{n/4}} (\frac{n}{e})^{n/4-n}
$
But I'm not sure on how to proceed from here or if this is even a valid approach.

We can directly prove the result without using the master method.
For $T(n)  \in \Theta(n!)$, we need to show $T(n) \in \Omega(n!)$ and $T(n) \in O(n!)$.
The first part is easy: $$T(n) = 16T(\frac{n}{4}) + n! \ge n!$$
The second part can be proven with the guess and verify method. Let $T(n) \le 2n!$, then we basically need to show $16T(\frac{n}{4}) + n! \le 2n!$ or $16\times2\times\lceil\frac{n}{4}\rceil! \le n!$ holds for large $n$.
$$16\times2\times\left\lceil\frac{n}{4}\right\rceil! \le n \times (n-1) \times \left\lceil\frac{n}{4}\right\rceil! \le n!$$

I like this approach. Rewriting $n!$ as $n \times (n-1) \times (n-2)!$ so the inequality becomes $\left\lceil\frac{n}{4}\right\rceil! \le (n-2)!$ may be a bit clearer.

Unrelated, bu are there any tutorials or more examples related to the guess and verify method? It always eludes when doing complexity analysis, and I want to practice with it to ingrain it

If you are asked to prove something, then you already have your guess handed out to you. In reality, guessing is a bit tricky; you fail multiple times until you succeed. I think CLRS contains some examples of this.

According to master theorem $T(n)=aT(\frac{n}{b})+ f(n)$, here we get
$$a = 16, b = 4, f(n) = n!$$
Thus
$$n^{log_{b}a}=n^2$$
As $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}{\left(\frac{n}{\mathbb{e}}\right)}^n$ (Stirling's approximation), we get
$$n!=\Omega\left(n^{2+\epsilon}\right)$$
for some constant $\epsilon>0$.
Also,
$$16f\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)\leq cf(n)$$
for $c=0.5$ and sufficiently large $n$.
Using the third case of master theorem,
$$T(n)=\Theta(n!)$$

how do we know which value for $c$ to try? Is it guess and check?
